# Xamarin Forms - toggle between button states

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this form in my Xamarin.Forms application where I have two buttons, that are both meant to update a boolean value. Depending on whether that value is true or false, I want only one of the buttons to be enabled. Think of them as a "door": one button sets the "exit" boolean to true and the other to "false". So when the "enter" button is clicked I want it to be disabled until the user "exits" by clicking the "exit" button.

CanExecute/ChangeCanExecute should be the way to go here, at least by my own knowledge - and that's what I've tried.
But it doesn't seem to be working, even when I abstract that functionality on a simpler content page.

I have attached a sample of my ViewModel's code, simplified for clarity.

I can't understand why I'm stumped by something that is so simple outside of MVVM conventions.

```cs
public bool _hasWorkerExit;
public bool hasWorkerExit
{
    get { return _hasWorkerExit; }
    set
    {
        _hasWorkerExit = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        EnterCommand?.ChangeCanExecute();
        ExitCommand?.ChangeCanExecute();
    }
}

public Command EnterCommand => new Command(SendWorkerEntry,WorkerCanEnter());
public Command ExitCommand => new Command(SendWorkerExit,WorkerCanExit());

private Func<bool> WorkerCanEnter()
{
    return new Func<bool>(() => hasWorkerExit);
}

private Func<bool> WorkerCanExit()
{
    return new Func<bool>(() => !hasWorkerExit);
}

private void SendWorkerEntry()
{
    // Do the work you're meant to do
    hasWorkerExit = false;
}

private void SendWorkerExit()
{
    // Do the work you're meant to do
    hasWorkerExit = true;
}
```

Here's the .xaml code for the buttons

```xml
<dxe:SimpleButton Grid.Column="0"
                  FontSize="13"
                  Text="Enter"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ButtonColour}"
                  PressedBackgroundColor="{StaticResource PressedButtonColour}"
                  TextColor="{StaticResource ButtonTextColour}"
                  PressedTextColor="{StaticResource ButtonTextColour}"
                  DisabledBackgroundColor="{StaticResource DisabledButtonColour}"
                  CornerRadius="0"
                  CornerMode="Round"                                             
                  Command="{Binding EnterCommand}"></dxe:SimpleButton>
<dxe:SimpleButton Grid.Column="1"
                  FontSize="13"
                  Text="Exit"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ButtonColour}"
                  PressedBackgroundColor="{StaticResource PressedButtonColour}"
                  TextColor="{StaticResource ButtonTextColour}"
                  PressedTextColor="{StaticResource ButtonTextColour}"
                  DisabledBackgroundColor="{StaticResource DisabledButtonColour}"
                  CornerRadius="0"
                  CornerMode="Round"                                             
                  Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"></dxe:SimpleButton>
```

Comment: can you show your the view part [.xaml] of buttons?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the .xaml - too big to post here - as it turns out the typo wasn't the only issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

Button 1:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding HasWorkerExit}"
```

Button 2:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding HasWorkerExit, Converter={Helpers:InverseBoolConverter}}"}"
```

One property alone should solve your problem.

```
public bool _hasWorkerExit;
    public bool HasWorkerExit
    {
        get { return _hasWorkerExit; }
        set
        {
            _hasWorkerExit = !_hasWorkerExit;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Invert Helper code:

```
public class InverseBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !((bool)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already use a single property. Plus the IsEnabled property means zilch when you use a MVVM Command, so that's not the solution here I'm afraid. Also, I might not get away with using a single property as the buttons need to be disabled until something else happens...

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to help. =/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of using the `Func<bool>`, you can use a simple method group for the Commands which should suffice:

```cs
public Command EnterCommand => new Command(SendWorkerEntry, WorkerCanEnter);
public Command ExitCommand => new Command(SendWorkerExit, WorkerCanExit);

private bool WorkerCanEnter() => hasWorkerExit;
private bool WorkerCanExit() => !hasWorkerExit;
```

Alternatively, this should also work:

```cs
public Command EnterCommand => new Command(SendWorkerEntry, () => hasWorkerExit);
public Command ExitCommand => new Command(SendWorkerExit, () => !hasWorkerExit);
```

Comment: Neither of the two alternatives seem to work - it could have to do with DevExpress and their own methods/triggers...

Comment: So maybe the `<dxe:SimpleButton>` doesn't check the `CanExecute` property of the command.

Comment: The puzzling thing here is... it does. On another project where I use the DevExpress controls, I enable a button based on whether the user has entered text on an input - and it works just fine. I might need to redo the whole code structure here, I'm afraid... I'm now thinking it has to do with the async function (the buttons' main functionality sends a POST to the database and those are sadly async by definition)

Comment: Alternatively, it's as simple as the CanExecuteChanged event not updating the UI when it's fired through a Command. Which makes sense but... how do I do what I want to do, then?

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that `CanExecute` is not called multiple times, so it is not a dynamic option to use for `enabling/disabling` the button.(The returning value actually is always false).

Suggestion: You could use a bound value `IsEnabled` instead of that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well that was the first thing I tried - but due to the button being bound to a Command, the IsEnabled attribute is ignored.

Comment: This is a known issue at **Github**. [The order of 'IsEnabled' and 'Command' should not matter #2758](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2758). You can follow the progress at **Github**.